# Subset a character vector in R based on a specific pattern

Tags: r, subset, data-manipulation

I have a vector of character ids, as rownames of a data frame in R. The rownames have the following pattern:

```
head(foo)
[1] "ENSG00000197372 (ZNF675)"   "ENSG00000112624 (GLTSCR1L)"
[3] "ENSG00000151320 (AKAP6)"    "ENSG00000139910 (NOVA1)"   
[5] "ENSG00000137449 (CPEB2)"    "ENSG00000004779 (NDUFAB1)"
```

I would like to somehow subset the above rownames (~700 entries) in order to keep only the gene symbols in the parenthesis part-i.e. ZNF675-and drop the rest part: is this possible through a function like gsub ?

Comment: Once the ensembl-IDs are stripped away, are the gene-symbols unique?

Comment: Dear Russ Hyde, yes, no duplicated values have been returned

Answer (score 3):

We can use `sub` to match characters that are not `(`, then capture the characters inside the `(` which is not a `)` and replace it with the backreference (`\\1`) of the captured group

```
row.names(foo) <- sub("^[^(]+\\(([^)]+).*", "\\1", row.names(foo))
row.names(foo)
#[1] "ZNF675"   "GLTSCR1L" "AKAP6"    "NOVA1"    "CPEB2"    "NDUFAB1"
```

---

Or using `str_extract` from `stringr`

```
library(stringr)
str_extract(row.names(foo), "(?<=\\()[^)]+")
```

#### data

```
foo <- data.frame(col1 = rnorm(6))
row.names(foo) <- c("ENSG00000197372 (ZNF675)", 
  "ENSG00000112624 (GLTSCR1L)", "ENSG00000151320 (AKAP6)", 
     "ENSG00000139910 (NOVA1)",
   "ENSG00000137449 (CPEB2)", "ENSG00000004779 (NDUFAB1)")
```

Comment: Thanks a lot akrun !! i was struggling especially for the first part of gsub with the pattern argument !!